# How to filter to check if any array element to match a condition in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

Currently I could filter with this MongoDb query

```
db.getCollection("entity").find(
    { 
        "NameDetails.Name.0.NameValue.0.EntityName" : /ABC/
    }
);
```

How do I loop through all the `Name` and then all the `NameValue` to search for /ABC/? If any of it matches, it returns as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use `elemMatch` or `unwind`.

If you know that it would match one element always, use `elemMatch`

or

If you want all the matching elements in the array, go for `unwind` then `group`.